# iOS Region Monitoring from web service

Tags: ios, web-services, monitoring, clregion

I am developing an IOS application that uses region monitoring.I get my regions to be monitored from web service. I want to reinitialize the regions when the user opens the application, meaning stop monitoring the current regions and start monitoring the new values from web service whenever the user opens the application(either from background or from start). When I do this my application is freezing while it gets opened from background. If I kill and open the application it does not freeze. I tried by commenting only the startMonitoring:regionName code and then the app does not freeze. Please suggest me if there is any way to initialize the regions at the start of application without freezing.

Comment: Maybe you should check that you are doing work on a background thread?

Comment: I tried doing it in background thread as well as main thread. Both freezes the app.